# Iphone Developer

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm a new Mac user and I was trying to download Xcode so I can start developing apps for Iphone, but it's asking me for my billing information...Do I have to pay to download Xcode and Iphone SDK, so I can start working on my projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Xcode is free. You do however need to have a valid credit card.

If you later plan on selling an app on the App Store, you will need to pay a [$99 / year iOS license](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) or, respectively, a [$99 / year Mac license](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/).

Comment: Isn't it $5 for non-registered developers?

Comment: @PengOne, I'm a non-registered developer and it shows as "Free" in the App Store. I do have an Apple ID and I did register for the free Safari program though.

Comment: Xcode is free in the Mac App Store.

Comment: @PengOne In the last year I purchased through the Mac App Store, Xcode 4 for Mac OS X Snow Leopard, that costed me $5. I don't know if it also costs $5 yet, but the version for Lion is actually free.

Comment: The 99$ is for being able to deploy apps to the appstore, not for XCode which is free. You also used to need to pay 99$ to run your developed app on real devices (rather then the simulator), not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: Yes, thats right. It's free on the Lion Mac Store.

Comment: @Danra, that's just what I said, Xcode is free, but you need to pay if you want to sell your apps. And you're right, it will cost you the same if you want to just deploy your apps on an iPhone for testing purposes, because you need to be a registered developer in order to provision your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for free as Apple developer at http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/
And will be able to download Xcode for Free, but you will not be allowed to test on devices only when you subscribe to the ios developer program